# Why was a drop immediately discarded?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I <s>failed</s> played some more TF2 today, and reached Medic milestone 3. I thus got a ubersaw. However, it was automatically discarded for some reason.

[image: enter link description here]

What happened? Is my backpack full? Is this item just locked for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to simply be a relic of days long gone. Indeed, clicking on 'view next' gives me:

[image]

Note how this item was "found", while the "DISCARDED" item was an [UNKNOWN] item acquired through a medic milestone (at least, that's what I imagine the monocolor medic image is about.)

Answer (score 6):

If you received an item that didn't appear in your backpack until later this is not unheard of. Usually it's a glitch or a synching error, but the item will usually be held for you and added to your backpack when it can. Restarting TF2 sometimes will help with this.

Comment: I heard that problem many times and also happened to me once. Usually sync problems are fixed in one/two days maximum, then it should appear in the inventory.

Answer (score 1):

On the screen that notifies you of the drop, there's a delete button.  Is it possible you hit that without realizing it?  It would probably be difficult, since I believe it also displays a confirmation to prevent such accidents.

Have you checked out your backpack?  It's possible your backpack is full.  If you don't want to go all the way in game, you can check [here](http://www.tf2items.com/).

Comment: [My backpack ins't full...](http://www.tf2items.com/id/badp?time=1299760339) ...but the mace _is_ there. Weird! Could it be I was awarded the same item twice?

Comment: @badp Is the spiked mace you're referring to the Boston Basher? [link](http://tf2wiki.net/wiki/File:C_boston_basher_sized.png)

Comment: It's possible that it was some fluke that said it was deleted but actually wasn't.  I've never seen what happens whenever you receive two of the same weapon at the same time (however that would actually happen), but I'd like to believe the drop system could handle it.

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I got droped.

Comment: @badp Hmm, I've played for a long time and gotten quite a lot of drops and I've never seen anything like that.  What did the screen say about it getting deleted?